# Building TexMaker 5 from source on windows

Tags: texmaker

I have been trying to build Texmaker from 5 from the source tarball on http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html

I have installed a fresh QT 5.9, and a fresh MSVC 2015 Community edition.

When I try the build, it gets all the way through to the link stage, and dies with some missing symbols. In particular the symbols from the windows pdf device appear to be missing - it's as if the .pro file only copes with linux/mac builds.

Has anyone managed to make this work?

Mails to the author have gone unanswered.

I have some changes (additional folding options, such as "Fold all sections" etc) that I would like to test and pass back to the mainstream.

Thanks in advance for any help.

The exact section of the build log with the errors in, is:

```
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\texmaker.exe @C:\Users\Robin\AppData\Local\Temp\texmaker.exe.7624.29140.jom
   Creating library release\texmaker.lib and object release\texmaker.exp
fpdfview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl CFX_WindowsDevice::CFX_WindowsDevice(struct HDC__ *)" (??0CFX_WindowsDevice@@QEAA@PEAUHDC__@@@Z) referenced in function FPDF_RenderPage
fpdfview.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl CFX_WindowsDevice::~CFX_WindowsDevice(void)" (??1CFX_WindowsDevice@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function FPDF_RenderPage
fpdf_sysfontinfo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::unique_ptr<class IFX_SystemFontInfo,struct std::default_delete<class IFX_SystemFontInfo> > __cdecl IFX_SystemFontInfo::CreateDefault(char const * *)" (?CreateDefault@IFX_SystemFontInfo@@SA?AV?$unique_ptr@VIFX_SystemFontInfo@@U?$default_delete@VIFX_SystemFontInfo@@@std@@@std@@PEAPEBD@Z) referenced in function FPDF_GetDefaultSystemFontInfo
doc_form.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EnumFontFamiliesExA referenced in function "int __cdecl RetrieveSpecificFont(struct tagLOGFONTA &)" (?RetrieveSpecificFont@@YAHAEAUtagLOGFONTA@@@Z)
doc_form.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetDC referenced in function "int __cdecl RetrieveSpecificFont(struct tagLOGFONTA &)" (?RetrieveSpecificFont@@YAHAEAUtagLOGFONTA@@@Z)
doc_form.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseDC referenced in function "int __cdecl RetrieveSpecificFont(struct tagLOGFONTA &)" (?RetrieveSpecificFont@@YAHAEAUtagLOGFONTA@@@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateCompatibleDC referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateFontIndirectA referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteDC referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteObject referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCharWidthW referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetFontData referenced in function "class CFX_ByteString __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::FPDF_GetPSNameFromTT(struct HDC__ *)" (?FPDF_GetPSNameFromTT@?A0x2555c822@@YA?AVCFX_ByteString@@PEAUHDC__@@@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetOutlineTextMetricsW referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
cpdf_document.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SelectObject referenced in function "public: class CPDF_Font * __cdecl CPDF_Document::AddWindowsFont(struct tagLOGFONTA *,int,int)" (?AddWindowsFont@CPDF_Document@@QEAAPEAVCPDF_Font@@PEAUtagLOGFONTA@@HH@Z)
fx_extension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptAcquireContextW referenced in function "void __cdecl FX_Random_GenerateMT(unsigned int *,int)" (?FX_Random_GenerateMT@@YAXPEAIH@Z)
fx_extension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptReleaseContext referenced in function "void __cdecl FX_Random_GenerateMT(unsigned int *,int)" (?FX_Random_GenerateMT@@YAXPEAIH@Z)
fx_extension.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CryptGenRandom referenced in function "void __cdecl FX_Random_GenerateMT(unsigned int *,int)" (?FX_Random_GenerateMT@@YAXPEAIH@Z)
fx_ge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl CFX_GEModule::InitPlatform(void)" (?InitPlatform@CFX_GEModule@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: __cdecl CFX_GEModule::CFX_GEModule(char const * *,class CCodec_ModuleMgr *)" (??0CFX_GEModule@@AEAA@PEAPEBDPEAVCCodec_ModuleMgr@@@Z)
fx_ge.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl CFX_GEModule::DestroyPlatform(void)" (?DestroyPlatform@CFX_GEModule@@AEAAXXZ) referenced in function "private: __cdecl CFX_GEModule::~CFX_GEModule(void)" (??1CFX_GEModule@@AEAA@XZ)
release\texmaker.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
jom: D:\Artifex\build-texmaker-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Release [release\texmaker.exe] Error 1120
jom: D:\Artifex\build-texmaker-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [release] Error 2
15:04:01: The process "D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project texmaker (kit: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 MSVC2015 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
15:04:01: Elapsed time: 00:41.
```